# Do I have to checkin before merging again in TFS2012?

Tags: tfs

I'm using Team Foundation Server 2012, and I don't really understand what just happened.

```
--> DEV -> MAIN 

             |-> REL X

                     |-> FIX
```

I made a bunch of changes and RI'd from FIX to REL. 
On checkin on REL i saw that something wasn't right, so i fixed it in FIX and merged again.
Then I wanted to checkin on REL, but the change wasn't there. I had to go into the file again and change an arbitrary spacer to get my pending checkin and merge again.

Comment: FWIW: It's a good practice not to do a RI (FIX->REL) before having done a FI (REL->FIX). That way you get all changes from the REL branch that were made after creating the FIX branch and you can verify that the fix still works with those changes. Also you get no conflicts when doing the RI and cannot pollute your release branch with changes that do not compile or that fail at runtime.

Comment: I should have tried to FI after that small fix and it would have most likely given me a diff between the two states. It doesn't feel intuitive though.